# What is the formula for mean time of collision in kinetic theory of gases?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinetic-theory

Does in the formula for mean time of collision we use $V_{rms}$ of $V_{avg}$ ?

Is the average time for collision Same as mean time for collision?

Comment: Please provide more information about your problem. Are you calculating time between collision with other molecules? Or time between collision with walls? What formula are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Average and mean are the same thing. $V_{\text{avg}}$ is used.

Comment: Please use MathJax for equations: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference